# Can an ActiveX control in IE download native assemblies it is dependent on

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, com, activex, c++-cli

I hope the title of this question makes sense.

What I want to know is if I develop an Active X control (developed in C++/CLI) that is dependent on other native (i.e. non-COM) assemblies, will the Active X control work in IE? I.e. will it be able to download the native assemblies locally or is it only the Active X control assembly itself that is downloaded?

Please ask for clarification if I haven't made any sense, my terminology on this may be off.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The ActiveX ctl itself must have its dependencies available to initialize properly. 
How would you initialize the ActiveX ctl to have it perform the download? (chicken or egg discussion).

You CAN however package the control with its dependencies so it will initialize.

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: Yes; you need to specify those assemblies as dependents in the control's manifest.  However this is a pain in the ass.  Just statically link everything into a single DLL.